# Play 2/Ebean ManyToMany JSON Results

Tags: mysql, json, jpa, playframework, ebean

I'm using Play! 2.1.4 framework with Ebean/MySQL.

The system basically keeps track of courses, and their requirements. Eg, if you want to take Advanced Art, you must first take regular Art. This is a ManyToMany Relationship, as I understand, but I could be wrong.

Here's my model:
@Entity
public class Course {

```
public static Model.Finder<Long,Course> find = new Model.Finder<Long,Course>(Long.class, Course.class);

@Id
private Long id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(         name = "course_course",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id1"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id2"))
private Set<Course> courseRequirements = new HashSet<Course>();

private String availability;
private Long category;

@Lob
private String description;

@Lob
private String otherRequirements;

private Long bucketId;
```

// Getters and setters...

Here's how I return the JSON to my frontend:

```
   List<Course> courses = Ebean.find(Course.class).fetch("courseRequirements").findList();

    JsonContext jsonContext = Ebean.createJsonContext();
    return ok(jsonContext.toJsonString(courses));
```

However, in the "courseRequirements" key in the JSON, it opens up a new array with full course objects in it. I just want to get an array of the course IDs it requires, for example:
courseRequirements: [3, 5]
means that: this course requires you to take courses with ID 3 and 5 first.

I rewrote my getter to this:
    public Set getCourseRequirements() {
        Set requiredCourseIds = new HashSet();

```
    for(Course course : courseRequirements)
    {
        requiredCourseIds.add(course.getId());
    }
    return requiredCourseIds;
}
```

because I thought that Ebean will pull that when trying to fill in the JSON key, but that's not the case.

How can I change it so that it only returns an array of course IDs for the courseRequirements key, instead of full objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **toJsonString(Object o)** you should use **toJsonString(Object o, boolean pretty, JsonWriteOptions options)**.

With JsonWriteOptions "You can explicitly state which properties to include in the JSON output for the root level and each path."

http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/text/json/JsonWriteOptions.html

Comment: I looked at that, but how can I use it to change the value of the "coursePrerequisites" key to use the getter from the model?